# ViewController not accepting value from other ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm working on a program in whirlyglobe.

When the program starts it animates to a part of the map from this code in the view did load

```
 [globeViewC animateToPosition:MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(-122.4192, 37.7793) time:1.0];
```

This works fine however I am trying to get the map to animate as well when I select a cell in my masterView controller so I have this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if ([[[[TypesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"regions"]objectForKey:@"region"]isEqualToString:@"Caribbean"])    
    {

        TestViewController *testView=[[TestViewController alloc]init];

        // Start up over San Francisco

        [testView.globeViewC animateToPosition:MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(-122.4192, 37.7793) time:1.0];

        NSLog(@"test");
    }
```

"Test" shows in the log but it doesn't animate to the spot on the map. 
I have added `#import "TestViewController.h"` to the top of this file and

```
@property(nonatomic,
strong) WhirlyGlobeViewController *globeViewC;
```

was added to TestViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WhirlyGlobeComponent.h"
#import "ConfigViewController.h"

// Map or globe or startup
typedef enum {MaplyGlobe,MaplyGlobeWithElevation,Maply3DMap,Maply2DMap,MaplyNumTypes} MapType;

//The Test View Controller brings up the WhirlyGlobe Component
// and allows the user to test various functionality.

@interface TestViewController : UIViewController <WhirlyGlobeViewControllerDelegate,MaplyViewControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
{
    /// This is the base class shared between the MaplyViewController and the WhirlyGlobeViewController
    MaplyBaseViewController *baseViewC;
    /// If we're displaying a globe, this is set
    WhirlyGlobeViewController *globeViewC;
    /// If we're displaying a map, this is set
    MaplyViewController *mapViewC;
    UIPopoverController *popControl;
}

// Fire it up with a particular base layer and map or globe display
- (id)initWithMapType:(MapType)mapType;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *parse;
@property(nonatomic,strong) WhirlyGlobeViewController *globeViewC;
@property(nonatomic,strong) MaplyViewController *mapViewC;
@end
```

Comment: I see you allocate a new testView.  Don't you need to message the existing view that has the gloveViewC

Comment: @jamihash well yes, but TestViewController and MAsterviewController are different, my Master dont see anything in my test view...hence why i allocate it? or am i doing it wrong

Comment: where do you instantiate testView property : globeViewVC ? It looks like it is null.

Comment: @Justafinger Added the testviewcontroller.h code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have things a bit mixed up...
Let’s suppose your masterviewcontroller is your car, your testvc is the axle and your WhirlyGlobeViewController are the wheels.

What you are doing right now is : i’m pushing a button in my car that does not have neither axle nor wheels, so i order a axle and i expect the (non existing) wheels to roll. That just don’t make any sense. You have to attach your axle to your car and get the wheels and attach them to your axle.

Your whirlyglobe is attached (initialized) in viewdidload (i guess) in testviewcontroller, but that method is never called.
You are saying that the line in testviewcontroller works, that’s because (i guess) you are using your testviewcontroller independently and viewdidload is called automatically.

From here you have two options. The first one is where your globe is available is all your program, and then it should probably be a property or an instance variable of MasterViewController 
instead of TestViewController. Then you could copy the code in your testviewcontroller’s viewdidload method to your masterviewviewcontroller’s viewdidload method. (the part where whirly globe is initialized)
Then you would have to call your animation by doing

```
[globeViewC animateToPosition:MaplyCoordinateMakeWithDegrees(-122.4192, 37.7793) time:1.0];
NSLog(@"test");
```

The other option is that testviewcontroller should be independant and only the globe should be in here. Then you should probably display somewhere that controller by using pushViewController or adding a childviewcontroller, for instance :

```
TestViewController *testView=[[TestViewController alloc]init];

//If you have a navigation view controller
[self.navigationController pushViewController: testView animated:YES];

//If you don't
[self addChildViewController:testView]; // testView's viewDidLoad will be called here
[self.view addSubview:testView.view];    
NSLog(@"test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TestViewController *testView=  [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page1" bundle:nil];
```

OR

```
TestViewController *testView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllrID"];
```

Comment: KI not sure what is wrong, is there a way I can test that i can access the nib from my masterviewcontroller?

Comment: It should work . . . N it just init the class file . . Doesn't invoke until its (element)should get loaded . . Init doesn't do everything . . You need to load the view r use some other way